# Not receiving beacons for airodump-ng to work

Tags: wifi, wireless

I have an AP close enough to me with high signal strength but for some reason I'm not receiving beacons from it. Since I don't have beacons coming in, I cannot perform `deauth` as well. One thing I'm certain about is that the AP is not hiding itself as I can see its name clearly.

I wanted to know what could be the possible reason behind it. Also what exactly is a beacon? What is it used for and when exactly does an AP send out a beacon? I referred the manual page but it only mentions that an AP sends out 10 beacon per second.

And last but not least, how will the generation of beacons be effected if I set my AP to hide itself?

Comment: you will need a patience: `while true; do aireplay-ng --deauth 10 -a <bssid> -h <mac> <iface>; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Beacons:**
Beacon frame is one of the management frames in IEEE 802.11 based WLANs. It contains all the information about the network. Beacon frames are transmitted periodically to announce the presence of a wireless LAN.

Your problem may because one of the following:

- Your wireless adapter is not on monitor mode
- Your wireless adapter doesn't support packet injection "check [this](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers&DokuWiki=8c01lcf8enceosivp8opuinbe3#compatibility) for compatible devices
- A hardware problem from the AP side. Check the RSS from the AP, it should be around -60 dB in strong signal case.

If you're using a Virtual Machine, be sure to use wireless USB adapter, not the laptop/pc wireless card, because the VM sees it as ethernet adapter and handle it that way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've checked for the promiscuous mode and also the support of packet injection. Moreover I'm not using VMware. I'm using Ubuntu based OS - Backbox. I tried it again and waited for 30 minuted before quitting the process and found that I do receive beacons but at a very low rate(1 beacon every 2-3 minute). Any idea why?

Comment: check beacons from other APs. if the problem still exist then you have a problem with your wireless card, or it's the AP itself.

Comment: I checked everything and seems like everything is fine. It must be the AP with some problem. I tested my friend's router's beacon without any problem. Anyway thanks for the time.